# WiFi Perimeter Fence

Tags: security, wifi

Is there a process to **virtually** dictate WiFi boundaries?  For instance, confining WiFi to a small office.  (This excludes directional antennas or faraday cages.)  I was **told** this was implemented at an office where I used to work.

Answer (score 2):

Really?  You can't.

If you want, I am sure that somewhere out there is software that will help you map out where your APs should have coverage.  Here is a random one from the Google:

http://www.ekahau.com/wifidesign/ekahau-heatmapper

Then, the carefully mapped signal will bounce all over the place and go through the walls and be accessible outside the building too, unless you have physical countermeasures.  The method is kind of OK at telling you where you expect it to work, but super bad at telling you where it won't.

It's possible, kind of, to triangulate a device's location and then apply an ACL based on that.  Some early-stage research in malicious node detection in public mesh or sensor array wireless networks tries to do this.

Seriously, use RADIUS and WPA2-enterprise, give people access only if you trust them, and set up a quarantined guest network.  That is your best line of defense.

Comment: This confirms my suspision that I was misinformed.